# How can I modify default column name whodunnit in Papertrail's migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, paper-trail-gem

I have implemented Paper trail for one of my entity and I want to override column name whodunnit in versions table created by generated migrations.

I tried to change the column name in migrations and places where I used it. But I was not able to run it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

What about [alias_attribute](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveModel/AttributeMethods/ClassMethods.html#method-i-alias_attribute)?

Do you really need to rename the actual column name?

Comment: Yes. Would prefer column name to be changed /overridden so that it is more understandable.